# Calculating Area of each Classes by Region in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, building

How could I calculate the area for each class of GHSL built-up layer for each district? I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var cities = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1");
var turkey = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Turkey'));

var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/BUILT_LDSMT_GLOBE_V1').clip(turkey);
var builtUpMultitemporal = dataset.select('built');

var visParams = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 6.0,
  palette: ['0c1d60', '000000', '448564', '70daa4', '83ffbf', 'ffffff'],
};

Map.setCenter(34.5, 40);
Map.addLayer(builtUpMultitemporal, visParams, 'Built-Up Multitemporal');


var calculateClassArea = function(feature) {
    var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(builtUpMultitemporal)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 38,
    maxPixels: 1e10,
    bestEffort: true
    })
    var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
    var classAreaLists = classAreas.map(function(item) {
      var areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item)
      var classNumber = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('class')).format()
      var area = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('sum')).divide(1e6).round()
      return ee.List([classNumber, area])
    })
    var result = ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten())
    var district = feature.get('ADM1_NAME')
    return ee.Feature(
      feature.geometry(),
      result.set('district', district))
}
 
var districtAreas = turkey.map(calculateClassArea);

var classes = ee.List.sequence(1, 6)
var outputFields = ee.List(
    ['district']).cat(classes).getInfo()


print(districtAreas)
```

And here is my error:

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=00000000000000000031):
Dictionary.set: Parameter 'value' is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over `turkey` which is 1 row from the GAUL Level 0 collection but you're referencing GAUL ADM1_NAME after the reduction, which doesn't exist in that collection.  You probably meant to be mapping over the Level 1 collection filtered to Turkey.